# Activity added now app is crashing

Tags: android

I had completed a simple map activity seperately from my main project and it was working fine but when the map activity was implemented into the main project + when trying to launch the activity, the app crashes any idea? here is the map activity code + logcat.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
            OnMapLongClickListener {

        GoogleMap googleMap;
        Location location;
        Marker marker;


        private void initilizeVars() {
            googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        }

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();
                initilizeVars();
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        /**
         * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
         * */
        private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }

        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(point)
                    .title("Marker")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

        }

**MAP XML:**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>




    </RelativeLayout>
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.attack.android/com.attack.android.Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.attack.android.Map.onCreate(Map.java:42)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     ... 11 more
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at maps.e.ch.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at maps.e.bf.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at eio.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:807)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4703)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>` to your manifest

Comment: crash -> post stacktrace.

Comment: logcat was actually posted, I improved formatting to see it without scrolling @njzk2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps 
API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
03-20 21:36:17.116: E/AndroidRuntime(7080): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

your logcat complains about missing permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

add it to AndroidManifest.xml to avoid SecurityException

Comment: yes i have added that to my code still the same logcat bar asking for new permission

Comment: Try clean project in eclipse an build again

Comment: Had added permission but forgot to clean and build cheers for all the help!